# Does XML support interface in OOP concept?

Tags: xml, oop, interface

IF yes, Could you show me some example in XML ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

No. XML is a markup language, not a programming language. OOP concepts can be used to represent XML in a program, but XML itself has nothing to do with OOP and does not have things like interfaces, classes, etc...